# looking for a jquery loading bar (with prcentage or not) during loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, progress-bar

I am looking for a `jquery` loading bar plugin (with percentage or not) to use during page loading like at the below web site (for example):

http://keramatifar.ir/index.php

but this loading bar appearance so sucks...

I googled for this with no good results; which words should I search for to get more examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an indeterminate progress bar, check out this site: http://ajaxload.info/. No jQuery required.

Or, if you want a determinate one, jQuery has one in its UI library: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/